# Secondary DNS name for heroku domain delegation

Tags: heroku, dns

I want to delegate my domain to heroku and can't do it as my provider requires **primary** and **secondary** DNS servers.
But heroku provides only single e.g. `myapp.herokuapp.com`

What can be a solution?

Comment: I think you're confusing the DNS servers with the application servers. There are 4 DNS servers for the herokuapp.com domain.

Comment: Where did you register your domain?

Comment: @Barmar, yes maybe I confusing.. how could I know theese 4 dns servers for herokuapp.com ?

Comment: @ThomasKlemm domain registered on nic.ru

Comment: Take a look at this [example](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53) using the Amazon Route 53 DNS servers and [this Heroku article on custom domains](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains). You're not supposed to change the DNS servers for your domain but add new records, something like "CNAME www.myapp.ru => myapp.herokuapp.com".

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

1. Add a DNS add-on, e.g. **Zerigo DNS**
2. Copy DNS servers from Zerigo Docs https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/zerigo_dns and set them in domain register:

> ```
> a.ns.zerigo.net
> b.ns.zerigo.net
> c.ns.zerigo.net
> d.ns.zerigo.net
> ```

Thanks for your answers anyway!